# How to segue from one tableview to another in Xcode using swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform, tableview

I'm hoping someone could give me a hand on a way to segue from one tableview to another. I have one tableview pulling information from parse.com and loading up the tableview cells. I would like to have it so when I click on one of those cells it brings me to another tableview thats pulling information from parse.com.

Answer (score 1):

The data you want to show in the second `UITableViewController` probably depends on which cell you tapped in the first one, right? Then you need to pass the data from your first `UITableViewController` to your second.

If you're using storyboards I'd suggest (I think this is the easiest way, but I don't know if it's the best) you create a segue from the first `UITableViewController` to the other, and naming it properly. Then use `prepareForSegue`to feed that data into the next Table. If you're just using a single Parse query you can simply copy the result array from your query to your class.

```
//In your class declaration
var objects = [PFObject]()

//In your query method
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
(objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    if let results = objects as! [PFObject] {
    self.objects = results }
}
```

Perform segue in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`

```
performSegueWithIdentifier("mySegue", sender: self)
```

And implement `prepareForSegue` to fit your needs.

```
 override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    //Check that the segue is the right one
    if segue.identifier == "mySegue" {

        if let destination = segue.destinationViewController as? MySecondTableViewController {
            //Grab the data from your array
            if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()?.row {
                if let objectToPass = objects[indexPath] as? PFObject {
                //Assuming your destination VC has a variable named object, type PFObject?
                destination.object = objectToPass
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then, in your next `UITableViewController`you can use `object` to perform a new query for the second table. Example:

```
//Second UITableViewController
//If you're using PFTableQueryViewController, use the queryForTable method 
let query = PFQuery(classname: "Animals")
query.whereKey("owner", equalTo: object) //Object comes from your first table
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
(...) }
```

Edit: This is almost exactly what they're doing in the link Steve posted, but I've made some examples hopefully fitting to your case.

Comment: this is kind of what I'm looking for. What i have is the first tableview with categories which there is 4 of them. when one of the categories is clicked it'll bring you to another tableview showing articles related to that category. And than from that what ever one of those cells was clicked it'll bring you to a view controller displaying information.

Comment: Then this should do it. If you send the Category PFObject to the Second Table View Controller, you could `query.WhereKey("Category", isEqualTo: object) ` or similar, depending how your Parse Database is designed.

(Above is assuming every article has a column named "Category" with a pointer to a category)

Comment: I have it set that like there is a class for the categories that is displaying the categories on the first tableview and than a class for each category that will hold the articles for the certain category they are.